# How to call a reactive object by its name?

Tags: r, shiny

Is there any method to call reactive data by its name? e.g. we can call 'mtcars' by get("mtcars"). I have tried but got some error:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("act_do", "Create Reactive Data"),
)

server <- function(input, output){

  observeEvent(input$act_do,{
    data <- reactiveValues(mt = mtcars)
    print(get("data$mt"))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: **Edit:** placed the print(.. into observeEvent(....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
server <- function(input, output){

  observeEvent(input$act_do,{
    data <- reactiveValues(mt = mtcars)
    print(get("mt", envir=as.environment(reactiveValuesToList(data))))
  })

}
```

Comment: Thanks Stephane. Actually, I was looking for the 'reactiveValuesToList' function.